# How do I Nohup an interactive shell-script?

Tags: bash, command-line, io-redirection, output, nohup

My Script is having 2 command-line arguments and then just couple of questions, after these questions the script will run for itself, I'm able to pass the command-line argument by just doing,

```
-bash-3.2$ nohup ./Script.sh 21 7
nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'

-bash-3.2$
```

Anyway to add the answers of these to-be-asked-questions with nohup?

Comment: What OS do you use? Is your `nohup` from coreutils?

Comment: `-bash-3.2$ uname -a
Linux -------------------------------- 2.6.18-238.5.1.el5 #1 SMP -----------05:52:39 --- ---- x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `nohup`, you could have your script ask these questions interactively and then background and `disown` the remainder of whatever else it has to do.

#### Example

```
$ more a.bash 
#!/bin/bash

read a
echo "1st arg: $a"
read b
echo "2nd arg: $b"

(
echo "I'm starting"
sleep 10
echo "I'm done"
) &
disown
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./a.bash 
10
1st arg: 10
20
2nd arg: 20
I'm starting
$
```

Check on it:

```
$ ps -eaf|grep a.bash
saml      6774     1  0 01:02 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./a.bash
saml      6780 10650  0 01:02 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto a.bash
```

10 seconds later:

```
$ I'm done
```